# if x >2 and <5: gives me an invalid syntax error. I dont understand why?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am using python 3.6 and i have written the following code:

```
l=[1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9]
a=0

for i in l:
    if i >2 and <5:
        l[a]=l[a]+1
    a=a+1

print(l)
```

I dont understand why I get a syntax error.

Comment: i >2 and i <5...

Comment: `2 < i < 5` or `i > 2 and i < 5`

Comment: `and` is a "binary operator", that is something that operates on two values, its left operand and its right one. `i>2` is a boolean expression that is a valid left operand, `<5` on the other hand isn't a valid expression.

Answer (score 4):

It should be

```py
if i > 2 and i < 5:
```

If you get confused with this, using parentheses helps.

```py
if (i > 2) and (i < 5):
```

The `and` operator compares the two operands on the both sides of the operator, and outputs `True` if both of them are `True`.

You can also try:

```py
if 2 < i < 5:
```

Answer (score 4):

You need each part of an `and` expression to be a full expression in its own right, i.e

```
if i > 2 and i < 5 :
```

However, in Python you can do this:

```
if 2 < i < 5 :
```

Which is clearer, more compact, and more Pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from your condition `i >2 and <5` in the if-statement. This condition is not Pythonic.

You have to transform it to something like: `i > 2 and i < 5` using the logic operator `and`. It is also possible to use the concise synthax `2 < i < 5`.

So, your code will become:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9]
a =  0

for i in l:
    if i > 2 and i < 5 :
        l[a] = l[a] + 1

    a = a + 1

print(l)
```

> **Output**

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```